# run nongui hcl onetest performance

Tags: rpt

I'm using ibm rpt v9.5(now hcl onetest performance), I have project created and able to run on gui mode. but can not run on non-gui mode using cmdline.
any one has occurred this issue?

```
cmdline -workspace workspace_full_path -project proj_rel_path -eclipsehome eclipse_full_path -plugins plugin_full_path -schedule sched_rel_path -suite suite_rel_path -varfile variable_file_full_path -servicename service -serviceargs service_args -configfile file_full_path -results result_file -overwrite {true | false} -quiet -users nn -vmargs JVM_args -exportlog log_full_path -exportstats/-exportstatshtml local_dir_path -exportstatreportlist stats_list -usercomments "any user comment"

-workspace "C:\Users\admin\HCL\hclproducts\workspace" -project test -eclipsehome "C:\Program Files\HCL\HCLProducts\hotperfse" -plugins "C:\Program Files\HCL\HCLIMShared\plugins" -schedule "Deleg_iteration_final.testsuite" -varfile "C:\Program Files\HCL\HCLIMShared\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.cmdlineexecute_7.2.2040.v20181116_1319\plugin.xml" -exportstatshtml "C:\Users\admin\Desktop" -overwrite {"false"} -usercomments "example"
```

I''m getting errors while execute - its saying path of Suite was not correct, or install correct java in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you see here:https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBLQQ_10.0.1/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.common.doc/topics/truncmdln.html

You have missed the "project" tag without the path

Your Command:
-project test

Expected:
-project "The path, including the file name of the project relative to the workspace"